# how do I find a value from a database using more than one criteria?

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve data from a single field based on information in three other fields.
As an example if I had a table with the following fields:
width, length, height, weight, and color.
I want to get the value for the field color where width = $value and length = $value2 and height = $value.

Comment: You mean, retrive data from database??

Comment: @Jithu he may be talking about tables too

Comment: You *almost* wrote the SQL query in your question!

Comment: You just wrote an SQL injection vulnerability in PHP. if someone can get a value into $value of "1; DROP TABLE yourtable;" you're in big trouble.

Comment: I am still having some trouble. It doesn't echo anything onto the page when I run the query. I am really new at this so I think I am probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL is almost what you wrote in your question!

```
select color from yourtable
     where width = $value and length = $value2 and height = $value
```

PHP:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT color FROM yourtable WHERE width = $value AND length = $value2 AND height = $value");
```

Comment: tried this but couldn't get anything to show up by doing and echo of $result. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd try some of the others here.  I wrote it after checking around on the web, but how that fits into your code, I don't know, because you haven't shown your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select color from table_name where width = $value and length = $value2 and height = $value3
```

I assume you mean using SQL....

Answer (score 0):

`select 'singleFieldName' from table where width = $value AND length = $value2 AND height = $value3`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    echo $query = "select color from yourtable_name
        where width = '".$value1."' and length = '".$value2."' and height = '".$value3."'";
```